# Swift: Can not get mime type form UTType from file extension .pkpass

Tags: swift, simulator, ios14, uttype

I am writing a method to get the MIME type from given file extension:

```
    private class func mime(from utType: UTType) -> String? {
        let mimeType: String

        if let preferredMIMEType = utType.preferredMIMEType {
            mimeType = preferredMIMEType
        } else {
           return nil
        }

        return mimeType
    }

    public class func convertToMime(fileExtension: String) -> String? {
        var utType: UTType? = UTType(filenameExtension: fileExtension)

            
        var mimeType: String?
        if let utType = utType {
            mimeType = mime(from: utType)
        }
                        
        return mimeType
    }
```

The test passes for `txt` and `mp4` types, but not `pkpass`.

```
    func testThatConvertToMimeConvertsFileExtensions() {
        XCTAssertEqual(UTIHelper.convertToMime(fileExtension: "pkpass"), "application/vnd.apple.pkpass")
        XCTAssertEqual(UTIHelper.convertToMime(fileExtension: "txt"), "text/plain")
        XCTAssertEqual(UTIHelper.convertToMime(fileExtension: "mp4"), "video/mp4")
    }
```

I tried to print the info of `UTType` and got these:

```
print(utType.description)
print(utType.tags)
print(utType.preferredMIMEType)


com.apple.pkpass-data
[public.filename-extension: ["pkpass"]]
nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default argument for the second parameter of the `UTType` [initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551510-init) that you are using is `.data`:

```
init?(filenameExtension: String, conformingTo supertype: UTType = .data)
```

So this finds a `UTType` that is a subtype of `public.data`. However, The `UTType` that you want (`com.apple.pkpass`) does not have `public.data` as a super type (i.e. does not conform to `public.data`). In fact, a `.pkpass` file is sort of like a `.framework` file - it's a bundle/package of things. (Try extracting its contents with The Unarchiver!) This is why the initialiser does not find the correct `UTType`.

Learn more about the hierarchies of `UTType`s [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html).

You can use [this other initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551513-init), and pass `nil` to the `conformingTo` argument. This will find you any `UTType` that has the specified file name:

```
let type = UTType(tag: "pkpass", tagClass: .filenameExtension, conformingTo: nil)
print(type.preferredMIMEType ?? "nil") // application/vnd.apple.pkpass
```

Also note the warning in the docs:

> Don’t attempt to derive the type of a file system object based solely on its filename extension.

Comment: thx @sweeper, your answer also fixes a similar issue when converting mime to file extension.